# Ruby OAuth 'doorkeeper' gem conditionals

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth, ruby-grape, doorkeeper

I am using the doorkeeper gem to use tokens to authenticate requests.

When I have doorkeeper_for configured as defined below, tokens are required, which is **good and expected**:

`doorkeeper_for :all`

When I set a conditional for doorkeeper_for to be the condition I actually want (allowing requests to local deployment endpoints without tokens)

`doorkeeper_for :all, :unless => lambda { request.url =~ /http:\/\/(localhost|127.0.0.1|0.0.0.0):8080/`

Or if I set this condition to any number of junk conditions:

`doorkeeper_for :all, :if => lambda { true }`

`doorkeeper_for :all, :unless => lambda { true }`

Then doorkeeper allows all requests to go through without tokens, which is **bad and not expected**.

Noting that I have a `require 'doorkeeper'` statement and that I've fiddled around with various include statements in my API controller such as `include Doorkeeper::Helpers::Filter`

This may have to do with a problem with Doorkeeper working with Grape, though again it is strange that it works just fine without the conditional. Any insight into why this is happening would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After speaking with the main contributor to doorkeeper-gem we've determined that it has to do with the use of Grape. This feature should work just fine with Rails based controllers:
https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/issues/426

Grape itself is supposed to be a closer-to-the-metal API framework and isn't necessarily supposed to be used with Rails, which contributed to this issue.

As a final note, there is a gem specifically for integrating Grape and Doorkeeper gems:
https://github.com/fuCtor/grape-doorkeeper